# If statement "Error message End if without block If"

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

```
If T = Empty Or SGg = Empty Or mugi = Empty Or Bgi = Empty Or xe = Empty Or _
   Area = Empty Or hres = Empty Or phires = Empty Or Sgi = Empty Or _
   kres = Empty Or pbari = Empty Or zi = Empty Or xf = Empty Or wf = Empty Or _
   Hf = Empty Or tauyhb = Empty Or nhb = Empty Or khb = Empty Or Tsc = Empty _
   Or psc = Empty Or Tsurf = Empty Or psurf = Empty Then _
   MsgBox ("Provide all the missing data on 'INPUT' sheet and in field units")
       Exit Sub
End If
```

**Question**:
I am getting an error message for above code line `End if without block if`. I don't see any problem in the code.

Comment: Is this a prank? :) Seriously though, please format it.

Comment: No Its not a prank. I assigned values to each of the above variables T, Bgi etc. I want to put a command that if any of those values are missing, an error message should appear. If I do it with TextBox it works, otherwise it does not. And please don't downvote me. I am trying to keep my question simple.

Comment: Besides, if you were to format the statement, the problem would likely disappear.  Unlike many languages, VBA is very sensitive to line breaks.

Comment: d'alar'cop     Thank you very much..... :) it works

Comment: @user2981046 That's excellent news. I know the relief. Might I suggest that you "tick" the answer. God bless

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices here.  Leave it all on one line as you have done, but remove the `end if` (the single line version of VBA's IF/THEN statement doesn't accept it).  Or you can add a line break before the `Then` keyword and another before the `End If`.

Comment: + 1 For the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need a new line after the "Then"